# how to clear the float to horizontally aligned div

Tags: html, css

I have three divs namely  `div1`, `div2`, `div3`.

All the div have `float:left` so they are horizontally stacked: how could I break down the third `div` by only applying styles to `div2`? I tried with `clear:both` and `clear:right` but nothing is working

Note: I want apply style only to `div2`

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red">div1</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red">div2</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red">div3</div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGdBq.png

Comment: Just to clarify the question: you can only apply styles to div2, and you want the third div to be on a separate line from divs 1 and 2?

Comment: why don't you simply remove float from second div? or is there any reason?

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule to the second `div`:

```
margin-right: calc(100% - 204px)
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqexXJ

---

This will apply a right margin equal to `100%` of the width minus `204px`
(that is `(100px + 2px border) * 2`)

Doing so the third `div` will shift down into a new line, no matter how wide is your viewport

Comment: but then user won't be able to add anything in left as too much padding.

Comment: I can't see it as a problem since it is not a OP requirement

Comment: yes i know but m just asking to you as m afraid too much padding is good practise or not?

Comment: You can use margin or padding as much as you need for the layout you need to create, there's no good or bad practice about it because the primary problem here is to find a workaround that achieves the result (possibily in a clean way), otherwise the logical answer would have been to just change the style of div3

Comment: agree with you as we must change the css for div3 but sorry for asking as m having only 2 years of exp in web development and as far as i know that too much margin or padding is wrong way so..sorry for asking :)

Comment: you're welcome, don't worry, your question is fine to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following... the `:nth-of-type selector` allows you select one or more elements based on their source order, according to a formula.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rfv46wn2/1/)

```
div:nth-of-type(2)
{
     margin-right:calc(100% - 204px)
}
```

Comment: Steevan: In future, please edit your post to include explanations/ updated fiddles, rather than posting in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this code to div2

```
float: none;
overflow: hidden;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6r17j5a/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood in the right way, you want to break down the third div like this.

```css
div{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}

#quadrado{
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="quadrado">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
    <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Original [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5o0gg36/1/)